# exec() explorer folder not operating

Tags: php

I wrote a PHP script, which is creating some files.

After it finished i want it to open a folder, where the created files stored.

```
exec("explorer C:\\test");
```

Unfortunately it isn't open the folder at all.

I check it in cmd as well where it is working.

I also tried this:

```
shell_exec("explorer C:\\test");
```

Any hint or advise is greatly appriciated.

Comment: Try feeding it the full path to the executable.

Comment: are you running this under a webserver? the web service probably won't be allowed to interact with the desktop and won't be able to pop up its window.

Comment: im running it at my home computer via Xampp

Comment: How do you mean to feed it with the full path? The folder is located in C:\test

Answer (score 1):

This can be done if your localhost is on your computer with windows  operating system (I use xampp). Any cmd command will work with exec();
So for your question:

```
$path = "C:\your path";
exec('start "" "'.$path.'"');
```

Will open your folder in windows.

Comment: I am using the "PHPDesktop-Chrome" platform to develop a desktop application that can be written in PHP. I needed to open Windows Explorer on the computer where my application will be installed through PHP. Your answer worked great! Thanks!

Comment: Should use single quotes ('), not double quotes (") because backslash is the escape character inside of double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use PHP's directory functions?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dir.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

I'm guessing that PHP can't open a GUI program, such as explorer, as it may not be able to access the user's display. Just my theory anyway. You could build a folder GUI using PHP and the aforementioned functions.

Comment: I'm understanding your point and eventually if it is the only solution then i will do that. I'm just hoping that there is a quicker solution for my problem like i wrote it above.